# show loader till a page completely loads in react

Tags: reactjs

in this Test component calling a api and inside success response am redirecting to a external page say for example (https:google.com), but the page is taking 6 seconds approximately to load, am having a loader component to show till the page is loaded, but it is showing for minimum time only, i need to show the loader component till the page is loaded. Can anyone please help in this?

```js
import React from 'react'
import './index.css';
import {
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const id_token = localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? localStorage.getItem('id_token') : '';
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': id_token,
    }
    axios.get(‘some api’, { "headers": headers })
      .then((response) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(response.status) == 200) {
          this.props.history.push('/loading'); // calling my loader page component. 
          window.location.replace(‘http://google.com’) // redirecting to external link, example google.
        }
        return console.log("data", JSON.stringify(response));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.props.history.push(‘/error’) // redirecting to error page, when we get error response.
        return console.log("error", error)
      })
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Test);
```

am showing loader component, but it is hiding once the page is redirected to external link, and it should stay till the external page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can by default have the `/loading` route of the router to show a Loader since you know the API is going to be called on `componentDidMount` and redirect after success. That way loader is going to be shown till the API gives a success or an error. Right now you're redirecting to `/loading` on success but it is also going to redirect the page anyways due to the next statement

OR

You can simply use the component's  state to show the loading state or the error state.

```
import React from 'react'
import './index.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading : true,
    error: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id_token = localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? localStorage.getItem('id_token') : '';
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': id_token,
    }
    axios.get(‘some api’, { "headers": headers })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false
        })
        if (JSON.stringify(response.status) == 200) {
          window.location.replace('http://google.com')
        }
        return console.log("data", JSON.stringify(response));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          error: true
        })
        return console.log("error", error)
      })
  }

 render() {
    const {loading,error} = this.state.loading
    if(loading){
      return <Loader />
    }
    if(error){
      return <Error />
    }
    return <div>Some Default Content</div>
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach is not correct. You are navigating to a new page(loading page) which is simply a naive approach. You can use a loading spinner component or just a text to show that your page is loading. One approach would be to use state. Set a loading state and initialize it to true. When the request is complete set loading to false. Use the loading state to conditionally render the loading component.

```
import React from 'react'
import './index.css';
import {
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {

  state = {
     loading: true
   };

  componentDidMount() {
    const id_token = localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? localStorage.getItem('id_token') : '';
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': id_token,
    }
    axios.get(‘some api’, { "headers": headers })
      .then((response) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(response.status) == 200) {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
          window.location.replace(‘http://google.com’) // redirecting to external link, example google.
        }
        return console.log("data", JSON.stringify(response));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.props.history.push(‘/error’) // redirecting to error page, when we get error response.
        return console.log("error", error)
      })
  }

 render() {
   const {loading} = this.state;
   let toBeRendered;
   if(loading) {
      toBeRendered = <Loading />
    } else {
       toBeRendered = <YourOriginalComponent />
    }

    return (
      <div>
          {toBeRendered}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Test);
```